# C++ function argument losing part of address

Tags: c++

I got a really weird bug(?) on Win8x64 driver in C++, which crashes the system.

```
bool funcA(typedef1 arg1, typedef2 arg2)
{
    funcB(arg1, arg2);
    return true;
}


void funcB(typedef1 arg1, typedef2 arg2)
{
    ...do something
    funcD(....)
    ....
}
```

Background info:
-- I did notice the driver crashes seemingly at random place of the codes, but didn't check why.
- I'm making some changes in "funcD()", not related to the crash. 
- I compiled the binaries with debug, and noticed (now several time) that it crashes at the beginning of "funcB".

Problem:
The issue is with the address of "arg2". The correct "arg2" address is there inside "funcA", which calls "funcB". But once inside "funcB", the address for "arg2" gets truncated.

e.g. arg2 = 0xffffe000'01ace148 while in "funcA", which then passes to calling "funcB". But inside "funcB", it becomes arg2 = 0x00000000'01ace148

I really have no idea how this can happen, so any suggestion welcomed!
Don't think my changes in the downstream "funcD" could have caused this, yeah?

EDIT:

Both "typedefs" are pointer to some different structs.

Notice "funcA" doesn't do anything except calling "funcB" directly with the exact same arguments it receives. And both "funcA" and "funcB" have the same parameters (different return type tho), yet "funcA" has no problem receiving the arguments' addresses.

Comment: Are you passing by reference or value?

Comment: I'm no driver expert, but did you double check if you are messing with calling conventions?

Comment: It sounds like `funcD` is spilling data onto an area of stack that doesn't belong to it.  Dangling pointer/reference, array overflow, etc.

Comment: I don't suppose somewhere along the chain of events you cast that pointer to an `int` and back?

Comment: Hopefully you aren't doing something sinful like passing an address as an int.  Might be easier to figure out if we saw the actual prototypes.

Comment: What is `typedef2` really?

Comment: I'm using WinDbg btw, and I'm referring to actual mem address of the arguments. They are both references. The thing is, "funcA" doesn't even do anything to the arguments... it immediately calls "funcB" with the same arguments.... yet somehow the address loses its upper 32bit?!

Comment: Both of the typedefs are pointers to some custom structs. So no, definitely no passing address as int or anything :)

Comment: Instead of describing what the typedefs are, post the actual typedefs. As in copy/paste them from your code.

Comment: `typedef struct _something {...stuffs...}something,*typedef2;` // I should add that I didn't write these codes... they have existed for a long time.

Comment: OK, not confirmed yet... but seems like it may be caused by WinDbg setting breakpoints! I ran thought the same code/binaries, without setting breakpoints, and it didn't crash.

Comment: @Andrew: I suspect that what's really happening is that undefined behavior in your program is being made to behave worse with the breakpoints and/or simply being run under the debugger rather than WinDbg actually being the cause of the problem.

Comment: @MichealBurr: This is actually not the first time I noticed WinDbg breakpoints seemingly affect the behaviour of the driver. Though in previous cases, it could be due to timing(?) issues as the software has to interact with hardware. But this time gets a bit extreme that's for sure. I can't track how the argument address got "truncated", when both caller/called functions even have the same arguments types, plus the caller function doesn't have any real code in it except calling other.

Comment: @Andrew: yes - breakpoints can affect timing sensitive code. But I'd be very surprised if they trashed a value in a register or memory. On the other hand, I suppose debuggers can have bugs, too; it seems to me that a bug like that would make the debugger worse than useless.

Comment: Can you post the disassembly of from the start of `FuncA()` to where it calls `FuncB()`? Hopefully the call isn't too far from the start.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is likely (or at least on the surface) caused by WinDbg setting breakpoints to those functions.

I tested the codes (compiled binaries) without setting any breakpoints in WinDbg, and the system does not crash. I tested both the debug and release build, both passed without issue.

Why/how tho? Somehow WinDbg messed up the addresses, or perhaps WinDbg magnifies a deep hidden problem? Anyone has similar experience that they solved?